# how to pass data from controller to directive using $emit

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I had strucked in passing value from controller to directive

I have two arrays in my controller

```
$scope.displayPeople.push(data.userName);
$scope.displayOrg.push(data.orgname);
```

i need to pass these data from controller to directive

my directive

```
<div>

    <div class="multitext-wrap blue-border">

        <ul inputfocus>

<!--<li class="tag" ng-repeat="list in selecteditemsdisplay  track by $index"  ng-class="{selected: $index==selectedIndex}" >-->
                <!--<span class="tag-label">{{list}}</span><span class="tag-cross pointer" ng-click="Delete($index,selecteditemslist[$index],list,searchid)">x</span>-->
            <!--</li>-->

            <li class="tag" ng-repeat="list in displayItems  track by $index"  ng-class="{selected: $index==selectedIndex}" >
                <span class="tag-label">{{list}}</span><span class="tag-cross pointer" ng-click="Delete($index,selecteditemslist[$index],list,searchid)">x</span>
            </li>

            <li class="">
                <input type="text" ng-model="searchModel" ng-keydown="selected=false" ng-keyup="searchItem(searchModel,searchobj)"/>


            </li>

        </ul>
    </div>

<div class="typeahead"  ng-hide="!searchModel.length || selected">
    <div class="typeahead" ng-repeat="item in searchData | filter:searchModel | limitTo:8" ng-click="handleSelection(item,searchobj,$index,searchid)" style="cursor:pointer" ng-class="{active:isCurrent($index)}" ng-mouseenter="setCurrent($index)">
      <div class="bs-example">
    <div class="list-group list-group-item active">

            {{item.displayConfig[0].propertyValue}} {{item.displayConfig[1].propertyValue}}


    </div>
</div>


                    </div>
                </div>

</div>
```

I was using $emit to send

in controller

```
$rootScope.$emit("displayEvent", {displayItems: $scope.displayPeople});


 $rootScope.$emit("displayEvent", {displayItems: $scope.displayOrg});
```

in directive

```
$rootScope.$on('displayEvent', function (event, args) {

                $scope.displayOrgs = args.displayItems;
                console.clear();
                console.info($scope.displayOrgs);
            });
```

by doing this i getting duplicates in place of org (both people and org wher coming )

how can i solve this problem please hepl me thanks in advance

Comment: $emit is not needed in this case, go with rilar's answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using $emit for communication between controller and directive is not a preferable.

you need to use "=" scope of directive to allow two-way communication between controller and directive like:

**directive**

```
    angular.module('YourModuleName').directive('yourDirectiveName',function () {
    return{
    restrict:'E',
    scope:{
         displayPeople:'=',
         displayOrg :'=',
     },
link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
}
}
});
```

**template respective to controller**

```
<yourDirectiveName displayPeople="displayPeople" displayOrg ="displayOrg "></yourDirectiveName >
```

Answer (score 3):

By declaring 'scope: false' you´re able to access the controller´s scope in your directive. 'false' means 'do not create an isolated scope, inherit the controllers'.

```
.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    scope: false,
    link: function($scope){
        //Do stuff with $scope.displayOrgs
        //Do stuff with $scope.displayPeople
    }
  };
});
```

This option will create an isolated scope and inherits the selected variables. This is a cleaner way of doing it.

```
 .directive('myDirective', function() {
      return {
        scope:{
           displayPeople:'=',
           displayOrg :'=',
        },
        link: function($scope){
            //Do stuff with $scope.displayOrgs
            //Do stuff with $scope.displayPeople
        }
      };
 });
```